# WordPress admin panel in different language

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I am trying to change the language of WordPress admin panel to Italian, and it's changing the language of the administration panel when I change it from Settings.

but when I registered the custom post type in my child theme, the custom post type menus in back-end are not getting into the Italian language.
below is my code for registering custom post type.

```
add_action('init', 'create_posttype_services');
function create_posttype_services() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Services', 'g5_helium'),
        'singular_name' => __('Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'add_new' => __('Add Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'new_item' => __('New Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'all_items' => __('All Services', 'g5_helium'),
        'view_item' => __('View Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'not_found' => __('No Service', 'g5_helium'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Services found in Trash', 'g5_helium'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __('Services', 'g5_helium'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', "editor"),
    );

    register_post_type('services', $args);
}
```

I am using Gantry Helium theme. Please Help!

Comment: Did you download your WP copy from https://it.wordpress.org/, or just regular .com English WP site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `load_theme_textdomain( 'g5_helium', THEMEPATH . '/languages' );` at the top of your `functions.php` file.

**Update:** 
What you might want to try is to load the text-domain from the parent theme as well. Like:

```
function child_theme_slug_setup() {
   load_child_theme_textdomain( 'parent-theme-slug', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_slug_setup' );
```

After this step make sure you placed those `.po` and `.mo` files into the `/wp-content/themes/child-theme/languages` directory.

Comment: how do you translate those strings? WPML string translation?

Comment: I am using the .pot file, and added my strings into that file.